# Preventing radio buttons from being clicked completely

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This has been bugging me for a while now. I'm trying to prevent users from clicking on a radio button depending if the user has the access to do so. The first solution was to do the following:

Without disabled

```
<input type="radio" name="my_radio1" id="abc1" value="5">
<input type="radio" name="my_radio1" id="abc2" value="0">
<input type="radio" name="my_radio1" id="abc3" value="1" checked>
```

With disabled with pre-selection

```
<input type="radio" name="my_radio2" id="abc1" onclick="return false;" value="5">
<input type="radio" name="my_radio2" id="abc2" onclick="return false;" value="0">
<input type="radio" name="my_radio2" id="abc3" onclick="return false;" value="1" checked>
```

With disabled and no pre-selection

```
<input type="radio" name="my_radio3" id="abc1" onclick="return false;" value="5">
<input type="radio" name="my_radio3" id="abc2" onclick="return false;" value="0">
<input type="radio" name="my_radio3" id="abc3" onclick="return false;" value="1">
```

As shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/93CqR/6/

This works great for radio buttons **ALREADY** checked but doesn't work for boxes that haven't been checked (as shown in example 3 above). Are there any known workarounds to this?

*Chrome and IE behave differently with this*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add a 'disabled' attribute to the ones not selectable. You don't really need the javascript.

see http://jsfiddle.net/Ma6TA/

```
<input type="radio" name="my_radio2" id="abc1" value="5" disabled>
<input type="radio" name="my_radio2" id="abc2" value="0" disabled>
<input type="radio" name="my_radio2" id="abc3" value="1" checked disabled>
```

**Update** I don't know the actual use case here, but if you aren't already, the actual check for this should be done on the server. Disabling or hiding the input from the user with javascript will enhance the UX, but a nefarious user could get around these things.

Answer (score 2):

I would use javascript to show/hide the elements that users have access to. For 2 reasons.
1) It's a better user experience if they can only see the form elements they can manipulate.

and more importantly
2) a disabled form field WILL NOT show up in the post/get array. I've had issues with this in the past and it is a very frustrating problem if you don't know why you're fields aren't coming through.

it could be as simple as wrapping js code in a php conditional ie...

```
<?php if($userCantSeeThese): ?>
<script>
$('.classOfElementsUserShouldntSee').hide();
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```